# Type safe way to hold multiple types within object

Tags: typescript

This feels like a very simple problem but I can't get my head around it or find the right example.

Let's say I want to create a `ServiceProvider` class that internally maps class instances to either a string identifier or the instance constructor. When used it would look like this:

```
let provider = new ServiceProvider();
provider.set('date', new Date());
provider.set('other', new SomeObject());
provider.get('date'); // I want TypeScript to know this is a date object
provider.get('other'); // I want TypeScript to know this is an instance of SomeObject
```

Or like this:

```
let provider = new ServiceProvider();
provider.set(new Date());
provider.set(new SomeObject());
provider.get(Date); // I want TypeScript to type-safely return the Date I provided
provider.get(SomeObject); // I want TypeScript to type-safely return the instance of SomeObject I provided
```

### Implementation

The solution feels very similar to the explanation given in [this article](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/01/06/typescript-2-1-keyof-and-lookup-types), however in the example the storage object is provided along with the key instead of being stored elsewhere. I explored things like the following example but `T extends typeof this.data` does not parse.

```
export class ServiceProvider
{

    private data: {};

    public set(key: string, instance: {}): void
    {
        this.data[key] = instance;
    }

    public get<T extends typeof this.data, K extends keyof T>(key: K): T
    {
        return this.data[key];
    }

}
```

I am unsure what type to declare `data` as; I cannot strongly type it (`private data: { [key: string]: Date }`) as I am dealing with unknown instance types, but if I loosely type it (`private data: { [key: string]: object }`) then I can assign any object but I think the type info is being lost.

Any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second approach (pass a constructor to get the sole instance of that constructor) is simple:

```
public get<T>({new(): T}): T
```

Comment: Maybe `new(...args: any[]): T` instead so it accepts any constructor?

Comment: OK, I like that - seems promising. But how would you store the data internally..? Couple of examples in the TypeScript playground: [using a Map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20ServiceProvider%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09private%20data%20%3D%20new%20Map%3C%7B%20new()%3A%20object%20%7D%2C%20object%3E()%3B%0D%0A%09public%20get%3CT%3E(constructor%3A%20%7B%20new()%3A%20T%20%7D)%3A%20T%0D%0A%09%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this.data.get(constructor)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D) or...

Comment: [using an array of instances](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20ServiceProvider%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09private%20data%20%3D%20Array%3C%7B%7D%3E()%3B%0D%0A%09public%20get%3CT%3E(constructor%3A%20%7B%20new()%3A%20T%20%7D)%3A%20T%0D%0A%09%7B%0D%0A%09%09for%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20this.data.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09if%20(this.data%5Bi%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20constructor)%20return%20this.data%5Bi%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09throw%20new%20Error('Could%20not%20find%20instance')%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D), both don't work for type-safety reasons.

Comment: @Pete: Yes; you will need a cast in the implementation.

Comment: @Slaks As in `provider.get(Date) as Date`? That's precisely what I'm trying to avoid. Or can I cast somehow within the service provider?

Comment: Try [instanceof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20ServiceProvider%0D%0A{%0D%0A%09private%20data%20%3D%20Array%3C{}%3E()%3B%0D%0A%09public%20get%3CT%3E(constructor%3A%20{%20new(...args%3A%20any[])%3A%20T%20})%3A%20T%0D%0A%09{%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%09for%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20this.data.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20{%0D%0A%09%09%09const%20elem%20%3D%20this.data[i]%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09if%20(elem%20instanceof%20constructor)%0D%0A%09%09%09%09return%20elem%3B%0D%0A%09%09}%0D%0A%09%09throw%20new%20Error(%27Could%20not%20find%20instance%27)%3B%0D%0A%09}%0D%0A}) in impl?

Comment: @Pete: Yes; you can cast to `T` inside `get()`.

Comment: @jcalz: That works fine, except that it's O(n) instead of O(1).

Comment: @Slaks, @jcalz, Perfect this now does exactly what I want, thank you! (For anyone interested, I'm now at `if (this.data[i].constructor === constructor) return <T>this.data[i];` within the getter).

Comment: @Pete: Using a `Map` will be faster.  `instanceof constructor` should also work.

Answer (score 1):

I will focus on the part where it takes `string`-valued keys and ignore the passing-constructors issue (which @SLaks has more or less correctly typed).

If you know in advance which keys go with which types, then you should just use a plain object:

```
interface ServiceProvider {
  date: Date,
  other: SomeObject
}
```

If you don't know in advance but would like to be able to add keys on the fly, then no statically-typed object will work for you.  What you *can* do is have the setter return a object of a new type.  TypeScript would then keep track of which keys go with which value types, but you'd have to *chain* your setters.  Here's an example implementation:

```
interface EmptyServiceProvider {
  set<K extends string, V>(k: K, v: V): ServiceProvider<K, V>;
}

interface ServiceProvider<K extends string, V> extends EmptyServiceProvider {
   set<K extends string, V>(k: K, v: V): this & ServiceProvider<K, V>;
   get(k: K): V;  
}


function emptyProvider(): EmptyServiceProvider {
  const data = {} as { [k: string]: any };
  const provider = {
    get(k: string) {
      return data[k];
    },
    set(k: string, v: any) {
      data[k] = v;
      return provider;
    }    
  };
  return provider;
}
```

Watch it in action:

```
let provider = emptyProvider()
  .set('date', new Date()) //chaining
  .set('other', new SomeObject()); //chaining

const d = provider.get('date'); // inferred as Date
const o = provider.get('other'); // inferred as SomeObject
const x = provider.get('whoops'); // error, "whoops" doesn't work
```

So that works, but the chain of custody of the provider is important.  If someone hands you a `ServiceProvider` of unknown origin, you can't possibly expect TypeScript to know anything about the mapping from key to value type:

```
declare const providerFromSomewhereElse: ServiceProvider<string, any>
const hmm = providerFromSomewhere.get('date'); // any
```

So I'm not sure how useful this will be for you, but that's the closest I can get to a dynamically typed object in TypeScript.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thank you, this is really interesting. I've not yet got to grips with why the type information is retained but I'll give it a good deconstruction and get my head around it. I'll give the bounty to SLaks but this is very much appreciated.